# JSONAPI : Patch node path alias

Tags: nodes, 9

I have content on a Drupal site and I want to patch to change their path alias. Here is how I do. It is giving me a 400 error: Syntax Error. I don't see where the syntax is bad. I am using Python 3 and requests

```
content = json.loads(data)
nodeEndpoint = endpoint.endpoint_url + f"/jsonapi/node/article/{destination_id}"

patchData = {
    "data": {
        "type": "node--article",
        "id": destination_id,
        "attributes": {
            "path": {
                "alias": content['slug'])
            }
        }
     }
}

articlePatch = requests.patch(
    nodeEndpoint,
    data=patchData,
    headers=headers
)
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: There looks to be an erroneous "f" on this line: `nodeEndpoint = endpoint.endpoint_url + f"/jsonapi/node/article/{destination_id}"`

Comment: I found the mistake. I was not serializing the json content.
Thank you.
data = json.dumps(patchData)

Comment: Now my problem is that this code doesn't do anything to Drupal. It is saying that the article is edited and sending the new article content including the defined path but it is not saved in the database. How to save the new path with the article ?

Comment: f is not erroneous. It is a formating function in Python. It helps to insert variable content in a string.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134730)